# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined:41

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, cordova

New to phonegap and ran into a problem on my first try. This works online, fails to start geolocation (or something) on the emulator, and gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined:41" error when uploading to my device.

The only thing I can think of is it is not loading the map js file, or some order is not being built correctly. All examples and projects i have seen conveniently skip actual device testing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>asd</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link href="css/codiqa.ext.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/codiqa.ext.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY0&sensor=true">
    </script>  
<style>
    html{height:100%;}
    body{height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
    #map-canvas{height:50%;}
    #content {
        padding:0;
        position:absolute !important;
        top:40px !important;
        right:0;
        bottom:40px !important;
        left:0 !important;
        z-index:10;
    }
  #bottom {margin-top:65%;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#page1', function(e,data) { getPos(); });
    var lat;
    var lng;

    function getPos(){ navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError); }

    function initializeMap() {
        console.log('init: '+lat+':'+lng);
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom:8,
            center:myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    }

    function onSuccess(position){
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lng = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(lat+":"+lng);
        initializeMap();
    }

    function onError(error){ 
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page1" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header"> 
        <h3>MapIt</h3>
        <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
    </div>     
    <div data-role="content" id="content">   
        <div id="map-canvas"></div> 
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <a href="#" class="add-markers" data-role="button" data-theme="a">AddMarkers</a>       
        <div data-controltype="textinput">
            <input name="" id="textinput2" placeholder="City and state" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="submit" value="My Location">
    </div>     
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried every solution Ive seen on here and the web. Surprisingly there is only a page and a half of google results with this title and phonegap. 
On my phone is does display everything but the map. 
It is this line that it fails

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
```

Thanks in advance.

```
****UPDATE SOLVED****
```

It was the white list 
There is two of them that need to be changed to this

1. in assets/www/config.xml
2. in res/xml/config.xml

I had changed the one next to the index.html file and didnt know the other was there in res/xml. Above the index.html file there is a res folder that I looked in and didnt see an xml folder.

Hope this bit of info helps someone else

Comment: Do you have     <access origin="*" /> in your config.xml?

Comment: <access origin="*" />
<access origin="googleapis.com" subdomains="true" />  Yes, ty I do

Comment: I checked the code in Chrome and FF and it works without problems. What about your key? Do you have enabled it for android? And I used `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', getPos);` for initialization instead the first line of script.

Comment: Yup, the key is all set and activated, I just changed it on here. My code works in the browsers too. Just not in the emulator of eclipse and not on my device. (galaxy s2). I even tried your code and got this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined:31

Comment: when you say it works in the browsers, dit you test with the default browser in the emulator and in your s2? (as it's what phonegap uses)

Comment: When I run it as an android application or download and install the apk, how would i test it in the browser? Its an app, not a mobile webpage. Though it makes sense that phonegap would be using the browser. But if it did, then why is it not pulling the src files like browsers normally do?

Comment: You said "My code works in the browsers too. Just not in the emulator of eclipse and not on my device." Many people test javascript/html5 code on the latest versions of chrome of FF and expect it to run the same in phonegap but as phonegap uses the default browser of the device, many htm5 api functions don't always work as expected (especially true for android 2.x)

Comment: Have you installed the phonegap geolocation plugin? If yes you should listen to deviceready before you call any function from phonegap.

Comment: That is what I am doing, and my phone does get geolocation. I console.log them to make sure it got that far. But the google variable is undefined. Its not getting the google api at all.

Comment: you should post your own solution as a separate answer, and accept it, rather than update your question with the fix :-)  That will be more helpful

Comment: Thanks, fairly new to actually posting here too. Will do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the white list There is two of them that need to be changed to this

```
<access origin="*" />
```

1.in /assets/www/config.xml

2.in /res/xml/config.xml

I had changed the one next to the index.html file and didnt know the other was there in res/xml. Above the index.html file there is a res folder that I looked in and didnt see an xml folder.

Hope this bit of info helps someone else